# Modify list element without list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list

I use this function to extract rgb values from images:

```
def get_rgb_and_rgba_values_for_next_three_pixels(image_data, pixel_type):
    if pixel_type == "rgb":
        rgba_values = []
        rgb_values = [image_data.next()[:3], image_data.next()[:3], image_data.next()[:3]]
    else:
        rgba_values = [image_data.next()[:4], image_data.next()[:4], image_data.next()[:4]]
        rgb_values = [rgba_values[0][:3], rgba_values[1][:3], rgba_values[2][:3]]
    return [rgba_values, rgb_values]
```

**Output:**

```
[[(255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255), (255, 255, 255)], [(255, 255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255, 0)]]
```

then I use this function to change all lsbs to 0:

```
def set_least_significant_bit_to_zero(rgb_values):
    return [value & ~1 for value in rgb_values[0][:3] + rgb_values[1][:3] + rgb_values[2][:3]]
```

**Output:**

```
[254, 254, 254, 254, 254, 254, 254, 254, 254]
```

My question is: how do I achieve exactly the same thing but without using list comprehensions in second function?

Comment: Do you have sample input data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to avoid the list comprehension - it is readable, Pythonic, and efficient - however, if you insist you can construct a result list by iterating over the values, appending the new value to the result list, and then returning the result from the function:

```
def set_least_significant_bit_to_zero(rgb_values):
    result = []
    for value in rgb_values[0][:3] + rgb_values[1][:3] + rgb_values[2][:3]:
        result.append(value & ~1)
    return result
```

You could also use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to make the `for` loop iterable:

```
import itertools

def set_least_significant_bit_to_zero(rgb_values):
    result = []
    for value in itertools.chain(rgb_values[0][:3], rgb_values[1][:3], rgb_values[2][:3]):
        result.append(value & ~1)
    return result
```